# What is the heaviest payload a modern theoretical glider could carry?

Tags: glider

Let's define a glider as any plane with a better than 0.75m/s minimum sink rate. Let's also assume it meets all EASA requirements for load factors and handling.

Knowing that the spar is an important limiting factor-- if not *the* limiting factor--  for payload capacity, and that the spar capacity is a function of material constraints, how much could a theoretical modern glider carry before the wingspan simply couldn't be increased any more?

I'm looking for answers to within a power of 2.

Comment: Hard to say but I'd guess in the hundreds of kg without reaching 500.

Comment: Why could you not design a glider with the wingspan of a 747 (but better low-speed aerodynamics)?  Or even larger, since wingspan of commercial planes is constrained by the need to park at gates?  You could even go with a multi-hull design, like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaled_Composites_White_Knight_Two

Comment: The sink rate appears to be the restriction to take into consideration. Otherwise, I would say, any aircraft could be viewed as a "self launching glider" so the payload would be quite large.

Comment: [Some were built to carry 20 metric tons or 200 pax with bag and baggage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messerschmitt_Me_321_Gigant).